# salesforce lightning error in Chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]Since yesterday in Chrome browser I am getting the following error when I am trying to open process builder page or trying to install a managed package in the developer org. Below screenshot when trying to install a unmanaged package.

Anybody else facing the same issue. Please see screenshot. Working fine in safari or firefox.
[image]

Error while trying to open process builder page

[image]

Comment: Which version of Chrome browser are you using?

Comment: Uploaded google chrome version